# Proper way to study parametric curves

Tags: calculus, curves, parametric

What is the proper way to study curves defined parametrically? For the sake of convenience, say the curve defined by the set of equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x(t)&=t^4+4t\\
y(t)&=t^4-2t^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
If we can eliminate the parameter $t$ and express $y=f(x)$, one can use one-variable calculus but usually the elimination is a difficult task, if not an impossible one. So, one should use a general method that does not need parameter elimination. Intuitively, I take the first derivatives
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lll}
x'(t)&=4t^3+4&=4(t+1)(t^2-t+1)\\
y'(t)&=4t^3-4t&=4t(t-1)(t+1)
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Setting first derivatives equal to zero we get
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lll}
x'(t)&=0\Rightarrow t&=-1\\
y'(t)&=0\Rightarrow t&=\{-1,0,1\}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Taking the second derivatives
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll}
x''(t)&=12t^2\\
y''(t)&=12t^2-4t
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Replacing $t=-1$ we get
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lll}
x''(t)&=12&>0\\
y''(t)&=8&>0
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
So I think there is a minimum at $(x,y)=(-3,-1)$.
For $t=0$ we get $y''=-4<0$. There is a maximum at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. For $t=1$ we get $y''=8<0$. There is a minimum at $(x,y)=(5,-1)$. The following figure obtained in Matlab supports my reasoning. I guess that $t=-1$ giving a minimum for both $x$ and $y$ explains the cusp-like look at $(-3,1)$.

What I am missing is a sound theoretical basis for previous analysis. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You could also use the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ and procede with analyzing first derivative, finding second derivative and analyzing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$